# How to separate answers

Tags: php

Below I have a piece of code which combines each answer per question:

```
// $questionNumber is simply n in value[n][]
// $answers is an array of value attributes from <input>s for this question

foreach ($_POST['value'] as $questionNumber => $answers) {
    // combine all the answers into a single string (e.g. ACE)
    $selected_answer = implode('', $answers);

    // continue onto inserting rows into the Answer and Questions tables
    // ...
}
```

So for Example:

```
Question 1: Answer: ACE
Question 2: Answer: BD
Question 3: Answer: C
```

But I actually want to seperate the answers so that it displays it like below:

```
Question 1: Answer: A
Question 1: Answer: C
Question 1: Answer: E
Question 2: Answer: B
Question 2: Answer: D
Question 3: Answer: C
```

So what my question is that what do I need change in my php so that it seperates them?

Is it suppose to be like below:

```
// $questionNumber is simply n in value[n][]
// $answers is an array of value attributes from <input>s for this question

foreach ($_POST['value'] as $questionNumber => $answers) {
    // combine all the answers into a single string (e.g. ACE)
    $selected_answer = $answers;

    // continue onto inserting rows into the Answer and Questions tables
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST['value'] as $questionNumber => $answers) 
{
    foreach($answers as $a)
    {  
             echo "Question: $questionNumber Answer: $a";

    }
}
```

It seems like a loop inside the loop will output what you want. If you need further help then run print_r() on $_POST and give me the answer.

Comment: Instead of doing an echo can I simply do `$selected_answer = $a;`?